# How to fix CS1503 error in blazorinputfile component?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I'm trying to create an upload file component for my blazor application.
Unfortunately I cannot solve the CS1503 error I keep receiving.
Here is my code:

```
<form @onsubmit="OnSubmit">
    <BlazorInputFile.InputFile @key=@inputFileId OnChange="HandleFileSelected" multiple="True" id="img" style="display:none;" />
    <label for="img" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Files</label>
    <label type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="ResetInputFile">Reset</label>
    <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Selected File</button>-->
    <ul>
        @foreach(var item in loadedfiles)
        {
            <li>@item</li>
        }
    </ul>
</form>
}

@code
{
    private Guid inputFileId = Guid.NewGuid();
    private List<string> loadedfiles = new();
    private List<IBrowserFile> allfiles = new List<IBrowserFile>();

    private void ResetInputFile() 
    {
        // Change id so that blazor re-renders InputFile as new component
        inputFileId = Guid.NewGuid();
        loadedfiles = new();
    }

    private async Task HandleFileSelected(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles();
        foreach (var item in selectedFiles)
        {
            loadedfiles.Add(item.Name);
            allfiles.Add(item);
        }
        await InvokeAsync(() => this.StateHasChanged());
    }

    private EventCallback<InputFileChangeEventArgs> HandleFileSelectedCallback => EventCallback.Factory.Create<InputFileChangeEventArgs>(this, HandleFileSelected);

    private async void OnSubmit()
    {
        CheckOut();
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
```

The error is on the `OnChange="HandleFileSelected"` on the second line in my code.
The error details consist of: "CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback"

I have tried multiple solutions from websites and nothing has worked so far, the error has not changed at all.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile) ? If it is the case, it is obsolete and you should use the built-in `<InputFile>` component instead.

Comment: I tried to change to <inputfile> but I only received more errors. What else would I need to amend to get it to work?

Comment: Make it this `OnChange="() => HandleFileSelected()"`

Comment: [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server)